# Astronauts returning from a mission find they are rejuvenating (lost teeth are regrowing)

Tags: story-identification, short-stories, anthology-book

I'm looking for a short story in an anthology (possibly Gollancz publisher) in the 60s.

Astronauts returning from a mission find they are rejuvenating - lost teeth are regrowing...

Comment: Welcome to [scifi.se]! This isn't much to go on, though. Please see our [guide on how to ask a good story ID question](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/q/9335/31936) and [edit] your question with any additional details you remember.

Answer (score 22):

This might be "[Silent Brother](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?55760)" (1956) by Algis Budrys.  It was in a Gollancz collection of Budrys' stories called [*The Furious Future*](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/pl.cgi?227105) (1964).

The protagonist is not an astronaut himself, or at least no longer, but the story opens with him watching the return of the first interstellar starship.  We learn that he was once an astronaut, but was badly injured (missing teeth, crippled legs, blind in one eye) in an accident and pensioned off.

After watching the return he finds strange things happening while he sleeps, like his TV being dismantled and strange things being built in the basement.  His gums also become sore.

It turns out that the astronauts brought back some kind of alien symbiotes who lack bodies, but who can repair human bodies and will do so in exchange for companionship.  His sight returns, his teeth regrow and his legs start working again.

The story was first published in the February 1956 issue of *Astounding* and you can [read it at the Internet Archive](https://archive.org/details/Astounding_v56n06_1956-02_EXciter-LennyS/page/n99/mode/1up).

Comment: Maybe using the spolier reveal system would be useful for that 4th paragraph.

Comment: @StephenG We don't normally spoiler story-id answers.  Plus the "spoiler" is revealed in every review or summary of the story anyway so it's not like it's a closely-held secret.